# Is there anyway to get the information now available in the Notification box?

Tags: feature-request

I'm wanting the information in the "Inbox" tab of the notifications in the top left of any SE website.  How can I get this or is it not yet available?

Answer (score 2):

no - the 'super-collider' is not exposed by the API.

you would need to synthesize this by maintaining a last visit data for a user and then polling each site's api endpoint for several queries filtered on last_activity or created_date.

this is possible but you would really need to be commited to getting the results.

Comment: Dang, I was just thinking today how easy it would be to make a SO notification bar app for android if the data was available. Just click the notification and pull up the link in the browser.

Comment: @bryan - the data is available. you just have to dig for it.

Comment: Even notifications from at replies from the chat rooms? That's one of my biggest motivations for this since the inbox also has those. I'd like to know when I'm at replied since I'm a moderator on the android stack exchange.

Comment: @bryan - hmmm.. no chat api. i did not consider that as i do not habit the chats. seems you are SOL on that front.

Comment: Yeah, the chat does not have an official API. BUT there are a couple of users on Meta somewhere who were trying to create one.